# Can a BLDC motor still provide max torque for holding position when I run it at 24 V instead of 48 V?

Tags: voltage, brushless-dc-motor, torque, robotics

I would like to do a Leg Robot project.

I have an AK80-64 BLDC motor from T-motor. The specification says it can be operated at 24 and 48 V.

Can the BLDC motor still provide max. torque for holding position when I run it at 24 V instead of 48 V?

Comment: What does the data sheet for the device say?

Comment: What are the winding resistance R and max current Imax specs? You need V = Imax * R to hold at max torque. So, if Imax * R > 24, then  no.

Comment: The motor itself probably (almost certainly) does not need more than 24 V for max holding torque. But if there is a motor controller involved, then you need to make sure the controller works at 24 V.

Answer (score 5):

Torque is essentially a function of current, not of voltage. As long as the motor controller can provide the current that is necessary for "max. torque" the supply voltage does not matter.

Since in your case the motor is standing still and speed is essentially a function of voltage, most likely the controller will regulate the voltage down quite a bit.

Of course, you cannot lower the voltage arbitrarily. At some point even the full supply voltage can't provide the desired current anymore, because of ohmic losses (especially in the motor windings).

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one 'max torque' (or max current) specification for a motor.

As you are talking about 'holding' a position, your limit will be the continuous thermal limit, for I<sup>2</sup>R losses in the windings.

This current will be well below the short circuit current with either 24 or 48 V applied to the motor.

The absolute maximum current you can safely apply to the motor for a moment is limited by the demagnetisation current, at which the permanent magnets are demagnetised by the field from the windings. Typically in brushed DC motors, this current is above the stall/starting current with maximum voltage applied. This may or may not be the case with BLDC motors, where the current limit might need to be enforced by the ESC.